# Can I use a Class/Methods to run through an array of WP Customizer settings to register them?

Tags: php, wordpress, testing, themes, customizer

I have an array of WordPress Theme Customizer settings that I want to register and output to the Theme Customizer, and they all register fine, and they all work perfectly.

This is where my problem is, $wp_customize->add_setting won't seem to pass the Theme Checker plugins' checks, it doesn't seem to like using a variable in place of an ID for the setting, even though the variable contains the setting name.  When I'm looping through the array I have, everything works fine in the Theme Customizer (all settings, control, sections and panels that I'm registering are there, and working and updating and even refreshes in the preview window), but in the Theme Checker plugin, I get this error repeated 100's of times when the tests are run:

Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '$' found in I:\xampp\htdocs\basic\wp-content\plugins\theme-check\checkbase.php on line 110

The line that is causing the problem is the one that registers the settings:

$wp_customize->add_setting( $set_name, $items['setting'] );

The "ending delimiter" that it's referring to is for the $set_name, but I can't find a way of passing this without these errors appearing, even though the functionality of the Theme is working perfectly.  Is there some sort of way that I can make the add_setting() method take my variable which holds my setting name?

The tests do complete, and it shows this related to the problem:

REQUIRED: Found a Customiser setting called $set_name in theme-customizer.php that did not have a sanitisation callback function. Every call to the add_setting() method needs to have a sanitisation callback function passed.

It seems to be passing the literal variable name, rather than it's contents, however, the Customizer functions as expected, and registers/saves the settings in the correct names that I've given in the array of settings.

Can anyone help please?

EDIT: I've added double quotes around the $set_name, and it has stopped outputting the 100's of errors about the delimiter, but I'm still getting an issue with the REQUIRED test that it isn't passing, giving the same failure as above.

Comment: Is the question about some issue with the built in feature in Wordpress, in the theme checker plugin or in your own code? When reading the question, it sounds like you've found some bug/issue in some third party code. It that's the case, you should talk to the developers of said code instead of here. If it isn't the case, then please show us your code so we can get a better understanding.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking whether the Theme Customizer method add_setting() can accept a variable as the Setting ID (the first parameter), and if so, how do I pass that variable, as just passing it in as the parameter doesn't seem to work, as the 3rd party plugin is reporting that the variable name is being passed.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You mean if you can do something like: `add_setting($someId, ...)` instead of `add_setting('hard-coded-id', ...)`? Sure, as long as the variable `$someId` contains a valid id. The method `add_settings()` won't know the difference. If that doesn't work for you, the variable probably doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: That was my first assumption, that it didn't contain what I was expecting, so I var_dump'ed the variable out, inside the foreach(), and on every iteration, it contains a valid setting ID.  The plugin "Theme Check" reports (as in my OP) that the setting name is being output into the add_setting() method (the part in my post that starts "REQUIRED" in my post.  The plugin was written by Theme Review Team, which I presume is the WP Team that Review Themes, so it should be pretty legit.

Comment: If a function/method expects a string, there's no difference between passing in a hardcoded string and a variable that contains the same string. As the function/method is concerned, those would be identical calls. It will just get a string. That's just how PHP works. If that doesn't work for you, then there's something else going on that makes it fail. If you show us the relevant code, it might be a bit easier for us to know what's going on. If it's the plugin that doesn't do what it should, contact the developers. And even the WP team can write bad code. They've done it for years...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I understand there is no difference between a string and a variable containing a string as far as the function/method is concerned. I'm going to move forward on the assumption that this is possibly an error in the Theme Check plugin code from the WP Team and contact them about it. Thank you for your help, I think this is the closest I think we can get for now